# Hyperlink to cell in Excel ONLINE

Tags: excel

In **Excel ONLINE** I want to create a **dynamic hyperlink to a cell** in the same sheet.

With this formula I get the cell reference:

```
=ADDRESS(ROW(B2);MATCH(G4;B2:G2;0)+COLUMN(B2)-1)
```

But how to create a link to that cell?

Is it possible at all?

[image]

Comment: Does excel online support this formula? `=HYPERLINK("#"&CELL("address",INDEX($B$2:$G$2,MATCH($G$4,$B$2:$G$2,0)+COLUMN($B$2)-2)))`

Comment: @isolated The cell formula is not supportet of Excel online